# Absolute positioning of tikz drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm working on a very tikzpicture heavy document and want to manually set the position of different shapes throughout the document. I haven't gone absolutely crazy, I'm using a background image as a guide.

For example, I want to set some small circles in very specific parts of the page and would like to later add some custom lines around and between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.5,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background.png}};

\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]
    \node [xshift=5cm,yshift=5cm] at (current page.center) {
        \draw (0,0) circle (1mm); %This line isn't working :((
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

At this point I can move the tikzpicture around but the `\draw` line doesn't let me compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HI ! Wellcome on TeX ! Please could you provide us a MWE ? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe and some examples of what you want

Comment: Look at section ["17.13.2 Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning"](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=249) in `TiKZ` documentation

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to add it @flav There it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `\draw` inside the curly braces of a node definition. These are made for the node text. I would suggest something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.5,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background.png}};

    \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]
    \draw ([xshift=5cm,yshift=5cm]current page.center) circle [radius=1mm];
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you insist on using `\draw` inside the node text you'll have to start a new `tikzpicture`.

[image: result]

Comment: Had to add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` but after that it works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @Groctel: This solutions works for me without `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`. I posted a different solution earlier which required calc.